# How I can run NUnit from command line and get xml result file?

Tags: c#, xml, nunit

I have following code in c#:

```
NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(new string[]
{
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
   "OpenShop.dll",                   
});
```

And I want to save result from this test to xml file after test ends. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need to run the tests programmatically like this?  Or can you just use the built-in console runner -- `nunit-console.exe` -- which generates Xml output already?

Comment: I need to do this programmatically becouse I am building an app to automatically runs tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're using the console runner directly, which if that's the case then by default it will generate an Xml file on each run.  It writes it to the working directory with the name `TestResult.xml`, so if you just want to save the file somewhere you'd just need to do this:

```
// Run the test like you're currently doing
NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(new string[]
{
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
   "OpenShop.dll",                   
});

// Save the file to match the name of the assembly, and so it is not
// overwritten on each run
File.Copy("TestResult.xml", "OpenShop-TestResult.xml");
```